# How can I change the default file presentation for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

Many tools raise a common Windows XP file chooser dialog.  This dialog offers various views: Thumbnails, Tiles, Icons, List, Details.

By default, I always get the List view, however, I almost always want the Details view.

Is there a way to make Details the default view for this dialog across all my applications?

Since the windows explorer method (shown below) of doing this does not affect these dialogs, perhaps there is a registry entry that can be changed to get the desired behavior?

Comment: There is a utility called "OpenWide" that accomplishes this. Search for "OpenWide Utility" It works on XP. Not sure about others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Double click on My Computer or use any existing Windows Explorer Window
2. Change the current view to DETAILS or whatever view you would like to make your default.
3. Go to Tools -> Folder Options
4. Click on the View Tab
5. Click on the button that says "Apply to All Folders"

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/maintain/folders.mspx) you can find some screenshots and instructions on how to do it.

**Edit**

As stated in the comments the steps given are for Windows Exporer, not for the Open / Save Dialog.

`The Open/Save As default view type can't be changed, unless its done from the actual source code in the way the file dialog is invoked. A workaround could be something like this http://www.file-ex.com/welcome.html`

Comment: Right, I had previously done that, but it does not appear to apply to dialogs.  For example, in Firefox, raise the Open File dialog, notice that the default view is not affected by the above preference.

Comment: Firefox is not a "Windows XP file chooser".
Regards,

Comment: So this is a bug with Firefox?

Comment: My apologies, now I see what you meant. The Open/Save As default view type can't be changed, unless its done from the actual source code in the way the file dialog is invoked. A workaround could be something like this http://www.file-ex.com/welcome.html

Comment: Putting the real answer in a comment makes it hard to find. Why not edit your answer to say this instead of something slightly off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier for others, I'm putting the real answer here:

The Open/Save As default view type can't be changed, unless its done from the actual source code in the way the file dialog is invoked.  A workaround is something like File-Ex v3 which works on XP (among other OS versions) and found at http://www.cottonwoodsw.com/fx3summ.html