# How can I change the default file window parameters for window 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management

This [How can I change the default file presentation for Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/140450/how-can-i-change-the-default-file-presentation-for-windows-xp) applies to XP and the directions and link in the answer are not applicable (Link broken).

I would like windows to come up set to "details" and I would like to choose just which details, in which order I want. Right the the windows come up with default settings that I would like to change.

Comment: How so are the instructions on the linked answer not applicable?  Aside from having to hit "alt" once to see the toolbar to select "View", they are still exactly the same for Windows 7...?

Comment: You just need to `1.` Click the **View Options drop down** from the **Windows Explorer** bar and select the **Details**  options `2.` Right click on any one of the **column headers** from the **Windows Explorer** and select the **More** option `3.` From that dialog window select the attributes you also want to show in all **Windows Explorer** viewed folders and press **OK** and `4.` Select the **Organize** option from up top, select the **Folder and search options**, and then from the view tab select the option **Apply to All Folders**... or press the ALT and then follow the link answer

Comment: When I follow the initial directions I have no "Tools -> Folder Options" item. There is no tools option. The only options I see are organize, open, share with, print and new folder. However the instructions following the number 4. in "many fish" comment lead me to the solution ( I think). Thanks. Unless this question should be removed, please make it an answer. :)

Comment: Organize>Layout>Menu Bar, now you will have the tools.